# Linear Equations Identification

Tags: linear-algebra

According to [my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR2PJ.png) , linear equations can have variables in square roots (part a and f) while rest of the internet disagrees (including me and my teacher). Why is the book calling such equations linear? Is this a mistake? or some kind of exception?

Comment: I would not say $x_1+5x_2-\sqrt{2x_3}$ is linear in $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Maybe  $x_1+5x_2-\sqrt{2}\:x_3$ was intended.

Comment: I'd say that (a) is linear in the variables, $x_1,\ x_2,\ \sqrt{x_3}$, but not in $x_3$.

Comment: Can variables be exponents in linear equations? [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/cMK7iwA.png)?

Comment: @Anon No they are then called exponential equations.

Comment: @user41736 Are you saying no to the equation I linked to or referring to a general rule? I plotted a graph of e^(x-y) = 1 and it resulted in a single straight line. The graph for e^(x-y) = 1/x wasn't a straight line. So my understanding is that variables in exponent (of a constant) are okay for equation to be linear. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Anon $e^{x-y}$ gives a surface in $R^3$. May be you have mistaken.Also $e^{x-y}=1$ holds only when $x=y$ so it gives a line.

Comment: So if an equation is exponential, it's can't be linear. Am I understanding this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly it is a mistake. In linear equations every variable have  exponent equal to $1$ or $0$.

Comment: That seems to be the case.